# remove values from target array matching from source array

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

for example I am iterating class slots using foreach
like

```
foreach ($result as $timeslot) {
       $time=strtotime($timeslot);
       $endTime = date("h:i A", strtotime('+' . $duration . ' minutes', $time));
       echo date('h:i', strtotime($timeslot)) . '- ' . date('h:i A', strtotime($endTime));

}
```

I have another array foreach which iterates over booked_slot like

```
foreach($booked_slot as $slot){
         $slot=strtotime($slot['start_time']);
        echo "slot<br>";
       }
```

The result of `var_dump` for `$booked_slot` is like:

```
[0]=>
  object(app\modules\admin\models\OrderItem)#195 (10) {
    ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(10) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(128)
      ["user_id"]=>
      int(73)
      ["location_id"]=>
      int(2)
      ["instructor_id"]=>
      int(16)
      ["order_id"]=>
      int(54)
      ["cd_id"]=>
      int(7)
      ["price"]=>
      string(6) "300.00"
      ["date"]=>
      string(10) "2018-04-12"
      ["start_time"]=>
      string(8) "10:45:00"
      ["end_time"]=>
      string(8) "10:55:00"
    }
```

and the result of `var_dump` of $result is like

```
    array(14) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "10:05:00"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "10:15:00"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "10:25:00"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "10:35:00"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "10:45:00"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "10:55:00"
  [6]=>
  string(8) "11:05:00"
  [7]=>


}
```

What I want is if $result have matching values for 
`$booked_slot[0]['start_time']` then that value is removed from the iteration of `$result`

To achieve this one option I tried is like

```
if(strtotime($timeslot) != $slot)
```

this works partly as where there is only one value in `$result` it works find, but if it has multiple values it works for only the last one.

The queries to generate the object array is like this:

```
$class_duration = ClassDuration::find()->where(['instructor_id' => $values['id']])->andwhere($cond)->all();
$booked_slot = OrderItem::find()->where(['instructor_id' => $values['id'],'date' =>$datec])->andwhere($cond)->all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach()` around `$booked_slot`, you are overriding the `$slot` value each time of iteration. So, only the last value is stored.

You could create an array to store all values, and use [`in_array()`](https://php.net/in_array) to check if `$timeslot` is inside:

```
$slots = [];
foreach($booked_slot as $slot){
    $slots[] = strtotime($slot['start_time']);
}
```

And to check:

```
if (!in_array(strtotime($timeslot), $slots)) {
    // $timeslot is not in $slots.
}
```

Comment: That is perfect. I am getting the result I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to become this is to put all booked slots in an array so you can check if your timeslot exists in this array.

```
<?php
$slot_array = array();
foreach($booked_slot as $slot){
    $slot_array[]=strtotime($slot['start_time']);
    echo "slot<br>";
}
?>
```

AND

```
<?php
    if(!in_array(strtotime($timeslot), $slot_array)){
       // not booked yet
    }
?>
```